# css3, flex, the items instead of wrapping to the next line, get minimised and aligns in single line

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a media query, to align items

above 600px :

```
colL, colC, colR in one line, 

and pck2 on the second line,
```

below 600px :

```
colL, colC in one line, 

and colR on the second line, 

and pck2 on the third line.
```

I regulate this by setting `flex row` container with `wrap`, and by setting width on each item. above `600px` `colR : 25vw`, below `600px` `colR : 100vw`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>

    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box; }

    body {
      width: 100%; }


    .indexImg {
        position: absolute;
        top:0; left:0;
        width : 100%; 
    }

    .cont {

        display: flex; /* container */
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap; /* nowrap | wrap | wrap-reverse; */
        justify-content: space-around; /* main axia : flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around | space-evenly; */
        align-items: flex-start; /* cross axis: flex-start | flex-end | center | baseline | stretch; */
        align-content: space-around; /* all container lines : flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around | stretch; */
    }

    .colL, .colR, .colC, .pck2 {
        display: flex; /* container */
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap; /* nowrap | wrap | wrap-reverse; */
        justify-content: space-around; /* flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around | space-evenly; */
        align-items: flex-start; /* cross axis: flex-start | flex-end | center | baseline | stretch; */
        align-content: flex-start; /* all container lines : flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around | stretch; */
        padding: 2vw;
    }



    .colL { background : yellow; }
    .colR { background : blue; }
    .colC { background : green; }
    .pck2 { background : pink; }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 499px) {
        .cont, .colL, .colR, .colC, .pck2 { width : 100vw; }
        /* colL { order : 3; } .colC { order : 1; } .colR { order : 2; } .pck2 { order : 4; } */
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) and (min-width: 599px) {
        .colC, .colL { width : 50vw; }
        .cont, .colR, .pck2  { width : 100vw; }
        /* .colL { order : 3; } .colC { order : 1; } .colR { order : 2; } .pck2 { order : 4; } */
    }


    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
        .colL, .colR { width : 25vw; }
        .colC { width : 50vw; }
        .cont, .pck2  { width : 100vw; }
    }


        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="cont" >

            <div class="colL" >
                <div class="f_g1 f_c3" >item 1</div>
                <div class="f_g1 f_c3" >item 2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="colC" >
                <div class="f_g1 f_c3" >img</div>
            </div>
            <div class="colR" >
                <div class="f_g1 f_c3" >item 3</div>
                <div class="f_g1 f_c3" >item 4</div>
            </div>

            <div class="pck2" >
                <div class="f_g1 f_c3" >item 5</div>
                <div class="f_g1 f_c3" >item 6</div>
            </div>

        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Items are wrapping. Not sure what you mean. https://jsfiddle.net/443vsjxo/

Answer (score 0):

You have a bit of a mistake in your media queries, so there is a gap in it between 500 and 600px.

`@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) and (min-width: 599px)` shoulbd be `@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 599px)`

You could also remove the `@media only screen and (max-width: 499px)` query to ensure there is always a fallback, incase something like this happens.

Answer (score -1):

```css
* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box; }

    body {
      width: 100%; }


    .indexImg {
        position: absolute;
        top:0; left:0;
        width : 100%; 
    }

    .cont {

        display: flex; /* container */
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap; /* nowrap | wrap | wrap-reverse; */
        justify-content: space-around; /* main axia : flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around | space-evenly; */
        align-items: flex-start; /* cross axis: flex-start | flex-end | center | baseline | stretch; */
        align-content: space-around; /* all container lines : flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around | stretch; */
    }

    .colL, .colR, .colC, .pck2 {
        display: flex; /* container */
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap; /* nowrap | wrap | wrap-reverse; */
        justify-content: space-around; /* flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around | space-evenly; */
        align-items: flex-start; /* cross axis: flex-start | flex-end | center | baseline | stretch; */
        align-content: flex-start; /* all container lines : flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around | stretch; */
        padding: 2vw;
    }



    .colL { background : yellow;  }
    .colR { background : blue; }
    .colC { background : green; }
    .pck2 { background : pink; }

     /*@media only screen and (max-width: 499px) {
        .cont, .colL, .colR, .colC, .pck2 { width : 100vw; }
        colL { order : 3; } .colC { order : 1; } .colR { order : 2; } .pck2 { order : 4; } 
    }*/

   @media only screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 599px){
        .colC, .colL { width : 150vw; }
        .cont, .colR, .pck2  { width : 100vw; }
        /* .colL { order : 3; } .colC { order : 1; } .colR { order : 2; } .pck2 { order : 4; } */
    }


    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
        .colL, .colR { width : 25vw; }
        .colC { width : 50vw; }
        .cont, .pck2  { width : 100vw; }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>

 


        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="cont" >

            <div class="colL" >
                <div class="f_g1 f_c3" >item 1</div>
                <div class="f_g1 f_c3" >item 2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="colC" >
                <div class="f_g1 f_c3" >img</div>
            </div>
            <div class="colR" >
                <div class="f_g1 f_c3" >item 3</div>
                <div class="f_g1 f_c3" >item 4</div>
            </div>

            <div class="pck2" >
                <div class="f_g1 f_c3" >item 5</div>
                <div class="f_g1 f_c3" >item 6</div>
            </div>

        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```